# Type of Lumber for carport load-bearing post replacement?

Tags: load-bearing, lumber, pressure-treated, carport

So I need to replace the 5 load-bearing posts on my carport due to visible rotting. Do you recommend using the standard Southern yellow Pine Pressure treated 4x4 lumber I see in your typical big box store or is there better material? The 5 posts the carport has now are all 4x4 lumber.

Comment: What are of the country are you in (e.g., would the carport roof need to support heavy snow loads)? And what kind of wood is used now? How big is the carport?

Comment: I am in a northern US state so we get 2 feet of snow at times. The current lumber is 4x4 and looks pressure treated. The size is about 28' x 12'

Comment: Since you already have a rot problem I would use pressure treated.